# cognalys verification error 550 and 551

Tags: android, confirmation

I'm using cognalys sdk in my app for user verification but i get the errors 551 and 550 which are not listed on their site and I don't know what are they, here is the code I use:

```
Cognalys.verifyMobileNumber(SignupActivity.this,"token",
                        "id","number",
                        new VerificationListner() {

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationStarted() {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationFailed(ArrayList<String> errorList) {

                        for (String error : errorList) {
                            Log.d("abx", "error:"+error);
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationSuccess() {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signed up successfully !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, SetPictures.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                    }
                });
```

instead of number I put my number from my code, I get the missed call but the toast "failed" shows up with error 550 in my log, can anybody tell me what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error codes: https://www.cognalys.com/androidlibraryerrors/
Android lib source code: https://github.com/cognalys/cognalys-android-library

Don't use the jar from their website. Download the one on github and include it in your project. Then you have to make a change in their code.

In the class CallListnerHelper, when a call comes, the incoming number is compared to a list of numbers they send. On my Xperia Z3c, the incoming number starts with 00. They send the list of excepted number all starting with '+'. The comparison always fails, so you have to handle that. Use the following library: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Answer (score 1):

We are now Sending number numbers list/array With + and 00 . Can you guys please re-check .We should know the problem is fixed or not . Thanks for the valuable update

Comment: Confirmed. It's fixed.